# template specialization using enable_if in function definition

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, enable-if

if I have the following function

```
struct Struct { template<T> void Foo(); }
```

How can I use `enable_if` in the function definition without repeating the declaration above?

```
template<T> typename enable_if<is_class<T>,void>::type Struct::Foo() { ... } // error: Struct has no member `Foo<T>`
template<T> typename enable_if<!is_class<T>,void>::type Struct::Foo() { ... } // error: Struct has no member `Foo<T>`
```

`enable_if<is_class<T>,void>` is just an example but is there a way to not repeat the declaration with multiple `enable_if` definitions?

it seems I'm forced to do this

```
struct Struct
{ 
   template<T> typename enable_if<is_class<T>,void>::type Foo();
   template<T> typename enable_if<!is_class<T>,void>::type Foo();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to not have to repeat yourself too much is to define them inline:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct Struct {
    template<class T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_class_v<T>> Foo() { /* ... */ }
    // same as:
    // std::enable_if_t<std::is_class_v<T>, void> Foo() { /* ... */ }    

    template<class T>
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_class_v<T>> Foo() { /* ... */ }   
    // same as:
    // std::enable_if_t<!std::is_class_v<T>, void> Foo() { /* ... */ }
};
```

or with *constexpr-if*:

```
struct Struct {
    template<class T>
    void Foo() {
        if constexpr (std::is_class_v<T>) {
            /* ... */
        } else {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
};
```

which makes separating the declaration and definition slightly less verbose:

```cpp
struct Struct {
    template<class T>
    void Foo();
};

template<class T>
void Struct::Foo() {
    if constexpr (std::is_class_v<T>) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, constexpr-if nails it, totally missed that one.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary You're welcome! Hope one of them works :-)